# My audio recorder replaces old recordings with new ones instead of creating a new file

Tags: java, android

The audio recorder i am building saves files in THREE_GPP format. The problem is that it replaces the new file with the old one so old files are lost.

```
mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    mFileName += "/AudioRecording.3gp";
```

I have tried this with no results:

```
mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
int entryNumber = 1;
do {
    if (this.mFileName == mFileName) {
        this.mFileName += "/AudioRecording.3gp" + "(" + entryNumber + ")";
        entryNumber++;
    }
} while (this.mFileName != mFileName);
```

Audio creation:

```
    mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    mRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);
```

I'm afraid that the code doesn't even target the proper scope here, but i have no other way of expressing to the compiler that it has to look for a file in that path.

Comment: use the equals method instead of == to compare the value of Objects

Comment: I used equals like this: "if (this.mFileName.equals(mFileName)) {". No difference.

Comment: Your comarison/increment seems to be a bit strange.  You should increment the number only.

Comment: did you also change the line: while (this.mFileName != mFileName) ?  Also: this.mFileName won't check all the existing files, it'll check one single name only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change how you are checking if the file already exists:

```
mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
int entryNumber = 1;

File mFile = new File(mFileName + "/AudioRecording_" + String.valueOf(entryNumber) + ".3gp");
while(mFile.exists()) {
   entryNumber++;
   mFile = new File(mFileName + "/AudioRecording_" + String.valueOf(entryNumber) + ".3gp");
}

this.mFileName = mFile.getAbsolutePath();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like:

```
    mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
 + "/AudioRecording" 
 + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) 
 + ".3gp";
```